# Merge Sort - program not checking two last positions.

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, mergesort

I have problem with my program. It works with smaller number of argument, but for instance for input `13 5 10 8 6 22 11 3 12 20 7 9 14 17 19 1 2 18` it returns `1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,19,20,22,2,18,`. I don't really know what may be wrong.

***Functions***

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int arrSort[], int first, int mid, int last) {
    int from = first;
    int to = mid;
    for (int i = first; i<last; i++) {
        if ((arr[from] <= arr[to] && from<mid) || to >= last) {
            arrSort[i] = arr[from];
            from++;
        } else if ((arr[to]<arr[from] && to<last) || from >= mid) {
            arrSort[i] = arr[to];
            to++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = first; i<last; i++)
        arr[i] = arrSort[i];
}

void mergeSortIter(int array[], int size) {
    int *a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i *= 2) {
        showArray(array, size);
        for (int j = i; j <= size; j += (2 * i))
            mergeSort(array, a, j - i, j, min((j + i), size));
    }
}
```

***Rest of the code***

https://pastebin.com/2ugS5ZpZ

Comment: Put all of the relevant code here. It's okay if it is a lot of code, so long as it is the minimal amount to reproduce.

Comment: You're indexing outside the array, causing undefined behaviour. Finding out where left as an exercise. (Insert some tracing output in `mergeSort`.)

Comment: **When you get this working**. It would be a good idea to get a code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop for mergesortIter() could be simplified (this may also fix a potential problem, I didn't check all the possible issues):

```
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j += (2 * i))
        mergeSort(array, a, j, min(j+i, size), min(j+2*i, size));
```

For the mergesort function, which is really a merge function, the pair of if statements are comparing data before checking if an index is out of range. It's also not copying the remainder of data when the end of a run is reached. Here is an alternative:

```
        if (from < mid && (to >= last || A[from] <= A[to])) {
            B[i] = A[from];
            from = from + 1;
        } else {
            B[i] = A[to];
            to = to + 1;    
        }
```

Note that the variables *from*, *to*, *last* would be better named as *left*, *right*, *end* .